# Estimate return levels for non-annual data

Tags: distributions, extreme-value

Apologies if this has been asked before - I have looked but could not find anything.

I intend on estimating return levels for average annual temperature data using a number of different distributions. This is made relatively simple when the quantile function is available:

```
p = 1/return_period
quantile(p, parameters, distribution)
```

However, I am also interested in return levels for temperature data averaged over 5 years. To prevent data being included more than once I extracted 5 year blocks e.g. (1900-1904, 1905-1909, 1910-1914...). However, I wondered how this changed the return level estimation?

I assumed the correct method would be:

```
p = 1/return_period/block
quantile(p, parameters, distribution)
```

However, I'm not finding much difference in parameter estimation (MLE) between the full dataset and extracted blocks, leading me to think the above method may not correct.

**How do you estimate return levels for 5 year block data?**

Comment: Can you describe or point to a definition of *return level* and *return period*?